# PosgtreSQL join tables on json field

Tags: sql, postgresql, jsonb

Let's say we have 2 tables-

**Employee:**

- `id integer` (pk)
- `name char`
- `code char`

**Status**:

- `id integer` (pk)
- `key char`
- `data jsnob`

Now here is the sample data of above tables:

**Employee**

```
+----+--------+------+
| id |  name  | code |
+----+--------+------+
|  1 | Brian  | BR1  |
|  2 | Andrew | AN1  |
|  3 | Anil   | AN2  |
|  4 | Kethi  | KE1  |
|  5 | Smith  | SM1  |
+----+--------+------+
```

**Status**

```
+----+---------+---------------------------------------+
| id |   key   |                 data                  |
+----+---------+---------------------------------------+
|  1 | Admin   | {'BR1':true, 'AN1':true,'KE1':false}  |
|  2 | Staff   | {'SM1':true, 'AN2':true,'KE1':false}  |
|  3 | Member  | {'AN2':false, 'AN1':true,'KE1':false} |
|  4 | Parking | {'BR1':true, 'AN1':true,'KE1':false,  |
|    |         | 'AN2':true,'SM1':true}                |
|  5 | System  | {'AN2':false, 'AN1':true,'KE1':true}  |
|  6 | Ticket  | {'AN2':false, 'AN1':true,'KE1':false}  |
+----+---------+---------------------------------------+
```

Now my goal is to get status and name of failure keys, employee code wise. For ex:-

[image: Result Table]

I am not an expert in sql complex queries, so any help is much appreciate.

**Note:** Above are just sample tables (name and data changed), but design is similar to original tables.

Comment: Unrelated, but: [Don't use char](https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Don%27t_Do_This#Don.27t_use_char.28n.29)

Comment: In addition to giving data in text format, it would be good to describe how you expect to get that output.  There is no failure or status column in either source table and it's unclear how the employee table is being used at all.

Comment: @Jeremy Thanks!, The idea is to loop over employee table and get result for each employee, also the status will be false if a single false is found in data.

Comment: due to the result data set 'AN2' should be false for Ticket, shouldn't be ?

Comment: @BarbarosÖzhan Good catch, modified it. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

you can use the function jsonb_each_text yo get key and value from jsonb type, and if we mix with sql and ... voilà,  the following query is a example for you case :

```
select employee.code,
case 
when dat2.count is null then 'TRUE'
else
'FALSE'
end as status, 
case 
when dat2.count is null then 0
else
dat2.count 
end as failures, string_agg as key  from employee left join 
(
select key, count(*), string_agg(code,',')  from (
select key code , (jsonb_each_text(data)).key,(jsonb_each_text(data)).value 
from status) as dat 
where value='false'
group by 1 ) dat2 on  (employee.code=dat2.key)
```

Comment: `case 
when dat2.count is null then 'TRUE'
else
'FALSE'
end as status` can be simplified to `dat2.count is null`

Answer (score 1):

As far as I can tell, you don't need the employee table for this (because you only want the `code` column which is also present in the JSON values of the `status` table). It's enough to unnest the JSON value and then aggregate on the code from that.

```
select d.code, 
       bool_and(d.flag::boolean) as status_flag, 
       count(*) filter (where not d.flag::boolean) as failures,
       coalesce(string_agg(key, ', ') filter (where not d.flag::boolean), 'N/A') as keys
from status st
  join lateral jsonb_each_text(st.data) as d(code, flag) on true
group by d.code
order by d.code;
```

The `filter()` option is used to only include rows in the aggregate that comply with the `where` condition. In this case those where the value for the code is `false`.

`bool_and` is an aggregate function for `boolean` values that returns `true` if all input values are `true` (and `false` otherwise)

Online example: https://rextester.com/PEKCZ52605

Answer (score 1):

Use a left-join query between those tables, and apply `jsonb_each_text()` function for `jsonb` type column.

*The trick is to use conditionals as `case when (js).value = 'false' then .. else .. end` for the aggregated columns :*

```
select e.id, e.code, 
       min(case when (js).value = 'false' then 'FALSE' else 'TRUE' end ) as status,
       count(case when (js).value = 'false' then 1 end) as failures,
       coalesce(
         string_agg(case when (js).value = 'false' then s.key end, ',' ORDER BY s.id),'NA'
       ) as key
  from Employee e
  left join
  (
   select *, jsonb_each_text(data) as js
     from Status
  ) s on e.code = (js).key
 group by e.id, e.code
 order by e.id;
```

where `(js).value` is extracted from `jsonb` type `Status.data` column

<kbd>[Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_9.4&fiddle=3e007aa24eabed5e7dba8cd49e576ed5)</kbd>